# Most efficient way to create a dictionary of empty lists in Python?

Tags: python

I am initializing a dictionary of empty lists. Is there a more efficient method of initializing the dictionary than the following?

```
dictLists = {}
dictLists['xcg'] = []
dictLists['bsd'] = []
dictLists['ghf'] = []
dictLists['cda'] = []
...
```

Is there a way I do not have to write dictLists each time, or is this unavoidable?

Comment: Are the dictionary keys what you actually want? Does it matter if they are random or an arithmetic progression?

Comment: Loads of answers guessing your keys are stored in a variable or similar and you are looping. Are your keys static like that? Or are they generated?

Comment: @MartijnPieters All (most?) of the answers utilizing keys stored in an iterable can be made static by just replacing the variable name with a list or tuple literal. Using a variable just makes the representation more elegant.

Comment: @JAB: Have you seen my answer, below? :-) It actually uses static list in a variable in one example. Contrast this with generating the keys (`keys = ['key%02i' for i in range(10)]`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) it allows you to set a factory method that returns specific values on missing keys.

```
a = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Edit:

Here are my keys

```
b = ['a', 'b','c','d','e']
```

Now here is me using the "predefined keys"

```
for key in b:
    a[key].append(33)
```

Answer (score 7):

If the keys are known in advance, you can do

```
dictLists = dict((key, []) for key in ["xcg", "bsd", ...])
```

Or, in Python >=2.7:

```
dictLists = {key: [] for key in ["xcg", "bsd", ...]}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you adding static keys, why not just directly put them in the dict constructor?

```
dictLists = dict(xcg=[], bsd=[], ghf=[])
```

or, if your keys are not always also valid python identifiers:

```
dictLists = {'xcg': [], 'bsd': [], 'ghf': []}
```

If, on the other hand, your keys are not static or easily stored in a sequence, looping over the keys could be more efficient if there are a lot of them. The following example still types out the `keys` variable making this no more efficient than the above methods, but if `keys` were generated in some way this could be more efficient:

```
keys = ['xcg', 'bsd', 'ghf', …]
dictLists = {key: [] for key in keys}
```

Comment: This is definitely most efficient, as the poster asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a for loop for the keys to add:

```
for i in ("xcg", "bsd", "ghf", "cda"):
    dictList[i] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

In the versions of Python that support dictionary comprehensions (Python 2.7+):

```
dictLists = {listKey: list() for listKey in listKeys}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, simplified my answer now that I have the confirmation. `[]` could also work in place of `list()`, as well, as used in someone else's answer.